# Need of ARP request before DHCP Offer

Tags: networking, dhcp, arp

When I connect my system with Router, the IP address is assigned by DHCP Server in that router. When the DHCP Request goes to the DHCP server from the system, it offers the IP address as broadcast. But the question is sometimes the DHCP server uses the ARP request before offering the IP address to the client. So what is the reason for using the ARP request from the DHCP server before offering the IP address . Someone of you may think that the ARP request is for checking the IP address which is ready to offer is already assigned or not. But my question is, the DHCP server stores the assigned dynamic IP address as table, So why should the ARP request is need instead of using the DHCP table for checking the IP is assigned or not.

Thanks,
Sathishkumar

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that. If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: I will delete the unanswered question bro. Is the answer provided for this question is right bro @DavidPostill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what is the reason for using the ARP request from the DHCP server before offering the IP address.

Make sure no other machine in the subnet already has this address.

> Someone of you may think that the ARP request is for checking the IP address which is ready to offer is already assigned or not.

Exactly.

> But my question is, the DHCP server stores the assigned dynamic IP address as table,

But the machine in question may have gotten this address (1) statically, (2) before a restart of the DHCP server which may have wiped the table, (3) by some other accident, for example a second DHCP server that is running in the same subnet (yes, this happens...)

So the only really safe way to find out is just to ask everybody in the subnet, with an ARP request.

Comment: These are all the reasons for making the DHCP server to make an ARP request as broadcast before offering the IP address or any other reasons may also available?

Comment: I had some other questions too bro. The question is many websites didn't told the flow of ARP request before offering the IP address. But the ARP request is also one of the flow in DHCP server to assign IP address. I didn't understand that why most of the sites are not mention this point !!